# How to get values from html selector using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the format in the page.html

```
IDENTIFIANT APPLE
johndoe@email.com
N° DE COMMANDE
MVV7277MWG
N° DE DOCUMENT
165153062372    
DATE DE LA FACTURE
23 févr. 2017
N° DE SÉQUENCE
1-1023986126    
TOTAL
3,99 €
FACTURÉ À
MasterCard .... 9337
Elodie Bregier
3 rue du général pol dupuy
angouleme, 16000
FRA
```

I want to create an JSON Object using jquery selector.

I have already seen one example:

```
var order = Create('Order');

// update data
order.data = {

  orderNumber: orderNumber,
  totalTaxExcluded: 0,
  taxRate: taxRate? taxRate[1].replace(" ", "") : "",
  totalTaxIncluded: totalPrice[3].replace(" ", ""),
  currency: currency, // ISO 4217 format
  orderItemQuantity: 1,
  orderQuantity: 1 // number of all items
};


var item = Create('OrderItem');

// update data
item.data = {

  orderNumber: order.data.orderNumber,
  name: name.trim(),
  price: order.data.totalTaxIncluded,
  currency: currency, // ISO 4217 format
  orderItemQuantity: 1,
  nbNights: nbNights,
  nbCustomers: nbCustomers,
  checkinDate: checkinDate,
  checkoutDate: checkoutDate

};

Result.push(order);
Result.push(item);
```

https://regex101.com/r/GetRkN/1

Comment: Not certain what question is?

Comment: @guest271314 i want to get the values from HTML and create object Json...

Comment: _"i want to get the values from HTML and create object Json"_ No HTML appears at text of Question. `JSON` is a string not a JavaScript object.

Comment: @guest271314 i have update the question, see the link to see html code...

Comment: You are just asking for something to be done without trying - because you are not even using selectors - and the code that you posted does nothing.

Comment: Please edit the post directly and clarify the question.